# Getting KeyError: 0 when attempting to access pandas dataframe by index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am currently working with a small toy dataset

```
"user_id","object_id"
1,1
1,2
2,4
2,2
3,5
3,2
4,1
4,4
5,5
5,2
```

And what I want to do is to create a table that indicates whether a user is associated with a particular object. To do this I have this method

```
def is_associated(df, target_object):
     a = (df.object_id == target_object)
     a = a.to_frame()
     a = a.join(df.user_id)
     a = a.groupby(["user_id"],as_index=False ).any()
     return a
```

While it's not the most elegant method, this successfully returns the following dataframe. For example if the target object is 1 I get

```
   user_id  object_id
0        1       True
1        2      False
2        3      False
3        4       True
4        5      False
```

However when I try calling a[0] I get a key error. Does anyone know what I might be doing wrong?

Comment: Try `a.iloc[0]` to get the first row. `a[0]` assumes 0 is a column name by default.